# Is there a way to get an object's class in a default method of one of its implemented interfaces?

Tags: java

I think this question is easiest to explain with an example:

```
abstract class Letter {
    abstract void callMethod();
}

class A extends Letter implements exampleInterface{
    void callMethod() {
        getStructure();
    }
}

class B extends Letter implements exampleInterface{
    void callMethod() {
        getStructure();
    }
}

interface exampleInterface{
    default Structure getStructure(){
        return new Structure(this.getClass()); // what should go here instead of this.getClass()?
    }
}

class Structure{
    private Class<? extends Letter> clazz;
    public Structure(Class<? extends Letter> clazz){
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }
}
```

Basically, I have a complicated structure that I want to have set up through an interface my classes can implement. To be initialized properly, the structure needs the original class that has implemented the interface. My question is how to get this class from inside the interface's default method. A solution I've considered is as follows:

```
class B extends Letter implements exampleInterface{
    void callMethod() {
        getStructure(this.getClass());
    }
}

interface exampleInterface{
    default Structure getStructure(Class<? extends Letter> clazz){
        return new Structure(clazz);
    }
}
```

where the implementing class passes in the correct class into the interface's function. However `this.getClass()` is the only thing that should go into that parameter. I'd like to avoid that repetition by putting something else inside the interface's method that can get this information itself.

Comment: It looks like what you need is a `Structure` factory class, not an interface with a method that returns a `Structure`. Unless you’re paid by the hour, the design you’ve shown is overly complicated. There’s no need for subclasses of `Letter` to implement the `exampleInterface`, just use composition instead of inheritance.

Comment: Just `return new Structure(this.getClass());`. It's the same `this`.

Comment: `getStructure` should be a method of Letter, not `exampleInterface`, then it'll work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is not so much the `getClass()` but that you need a `Letter` in your `Structure`. So either cast the get class to the subclass

```
interface exampleInterface{
    default Structure getStructure(){
        return new Structure((Class<Letter>)this.getClass()); // what should go here instead of this.getClass()?
    }
}
```

or change the Structure to accept the interface

```
class Structure{
    private Class<? extends exampleInterface> clazz;
    public Structure(Class<? extends exampleInterface> clazz){
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the first example works how I want. I hadn't considered that would work because I thought using `this.getClass()` could only return a `exampleInterface.class`, which is unrelated to `Letter` and so not be castable to `? extends Letter`.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better to split the interface from the default behavior if that behavior doesn't actually work for all possible implementations.

```
interface ExampleInterface {
    // non-Letters may want to implement this interface
    // if only Letters should be able implement it then that's just more evidence you should make it into an abstract class
    // or consider "composition over inheritance": ExampleInterface becomes a class that manages a Letter that it keeps as a field rather than requiring itself to be a Letter
    // or consider making the default into a static method that, even if it can't completely remove the noise from your subclasses, means you only do the actually complicated stuff you want to keep DRY in one place
    Structure getStructure();
}
abstract class LetterWithStructure extends Letter implements ExampleInterface { // Letter subclasses can subclass this instead if they want the default getStructure
    @Override public Structure getStructure() { return new Structure(getClass()); }
}
class A extends LetterWithStructure {
    @Override void callMethod() { getStructure(); }
}
class B extends LetterWithStructure {
    @Override void callMethod() { getStructure(); }
}
class C implements ExampleInterface { // example non-Letter with its own getStructure
    public Structure structure;
    @Override public Structure getStructure() { return structure; }
}
class D<L extends Letter> extends Letter implements ExampleInterface { // example Letter with non-default getStructure
    public L payload;
    @Override public Structure getStructure() { return new Structure(payload.getClass()); }
    @Override void callMethod() { payload.callMethod(); }
}
```

You see this pattern e.g. in Java's own collections library. For example, the `List<T>` interface has multiple possible "default" implementations. Therefore (aside from the fact that `List<T>` predates `default` methods!) it only makes sense to put no/minimal behavior into `List<T>` and put the defaults into separate implementing classes like `AbstractList<T>` and `AbstractSequentialList<T>`.